# Minimal supported platform versions for xamarin.uitest

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I'm currently looking into test frameworks that run UI-tests for Xamarin projects. I've narrowed it down to two options:

- Xamarin.UITest
- Appium

However, it's unknown what the minimal versions of iOS and Android are, which are supported in Xamarin.UITest. I've found an old form [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47586/what-is-the-minimum-android-version-supported-by-xamarin-forms) that suggests there are indeed minimal versions. However, the answer that is given, redirects to the new Microsoft documentation which doesn't contain those versions.

Does anyone know the minimally supported versions of Android and iOS which Xamarin.UITest supports?

**Edit**

After the suggestion of James Lavery to contact App Center, i've got the following answer from Microsoft:

*Hi There, Thanks for writing to us! Xamarin.UITest will support all version of Android and IOS, the only thing you need to check is the app which you are running in supported respective versions.
Please refer the below article the list of devices and respective versions we have
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/devices*

James Lavery has gotten the same answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response I've had from Microsoft is:

*Hi There, Thanks for writing to us! Xamarin.UITest will support all version of Android and IOS, the only thing you need to check is the app which you are running in supported respective versions.
Please refer the below article the list of devices and respective versions we have*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/devices

Answer (score 0):

If you have an App Center account, I suggest you contact the support team there (button at the bottom right of the portal screen). They respond pretty quickly.

If you don't have an App Center account, let me know and I'll pose the question for you.